# RestKit Mapping concatenate

Tags: objective-c, json, restkit, restkit-0.20

I have some json like this :

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "datas": [
                {
                    "date": "2015-01-20T00:00+0100"
                },
                {
                    "date": "2015-01-21T00:00+0100"
                }
            ],
            "id": "100"
        },
        {
            "datas": [
                {
                    "date": "2015-01-20T00:00+0100"
                },
                {
                    "date": "2015-01-21T00:00+0100"
                }
            ],
            "id": "200"
        }
    ],
    "id": "itemset1"
}
```

I have an Object, data, with some info and a date.
I would like to set a property identifier to a value composed with the parent id and the date, like `100_2015-01-20T00:00+0100`

I can get the parent id in my identifier with the following code :

```
[dataMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{"@parent.id":@"identifier",...}];
```

Is they a way do concatenate value with RestKit mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't concatenate directly, no. Instead you would store both of the attributes and provide a public method which concatenates and returns the value. Or perhaps set the variables to transient and on `willSave` (or similar) convert them and persistently store the concatenated value.